# Is the basis of the vector subspace u(1,2) itself?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

I don't understand the basis of a vector subspace. Would any $x$ in $F^k,$ where $F$ is the field set, be a basis?

Comment: First, a basis of any vector space is built from elements (i.e. vectors) of the space itself. Second, this set of vectors must fulfill some conditions in order to be a basis. Now, the elements in $\;F^k\;$ are of the form $\;(a_1,...,a_k)\;$ , with $\;a_i\in F\;$ . If this much isn't crystal clear so far there is no point to continue...

Comment: @DonAntonio so u(1,2) alone would not form a vector space therefore I need another independent vector, is that right?

Comment: @Val: What is $u(1,2)$? What is the vector space in consideration here? Your question is very unclear.

Comment: @learner u is an element of the real set and let the vector space be the Real set squared

Comment: This has nothing to do with $F$ or with $k,$ so it can't be right.  Go back and read the comment from DonAntonio again.

Comment: What is the subspace you're talking about then? Do you need to find a basis of $\Bbb R^2$ or a basis of some subspace of $\Bbb R^2$? Also, are you familiar with the terms "linearly independent set" and "generating/spanning set"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So you're taking all scalar ($u \in \mathbb{R}$) multiples of $(1,2) \in \mathbb{R}^2$? That forms a subspace of $\mathbb{R}^2$ - check! - and indeed $(1,2)$ forms a basis for the subspace - make sure you are happy why the element $(1,2)$ spans the space and is necessarily linearly independent.